# Selenium Remote won't continue past JavaScript error that real browsers will

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to scrape a third party site in a python program that runs on a headless server. The third party site uses a weird home-grown authentication scheme which is why I'm using Selenium instead of BeautifulSoup. I've been doing this daily for over a year with no problems.

In the last couple of days, the site has introduced some new code that causes a JavaScript error on their main page. "Real" browsers emit an error message but continue to run the rest of the JavaScript on the page that actually loads the content I'm after into the DOM, but the Selenium remote server hits that JavaScript error and aborts, and stops loading the page, leaving me without the content I'm trying to scrape.

Here is my code:

```
class SeleniumHandler(ErrorHandler):
    def check_response(self, response):
        try:
            super(SeleniumHandler, self).check_response(response)
        except Exception:
            pass

def login(use_firefox=False):
    """ This method logs you in and takes you to the flight plan list """
    if use_firefox:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    else:
        capabilities = {
            "browserName": "htmlunit",
            "version": "firefox",
            "platform": "ANY",
            "javascriptEnabled": True,
            "acceptInsecureCerts": True,
            "acceptSslCerts": True,
        }
        driver = webdriver.Remote(
            "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
            capabilities,
        )
        #driver.error_handler = SeleniumHandler()

    driver.get("https://www.foo.bar.com/")
```

If I call login with `use_firefox=True)` it works fine, but that's not an option on my headless server. If I look in the JavaScript console on a real browser, I'll see something like:

```
menu.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (menu.js:9)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2)
    at menuBuilder (menu.js:8)
    at menu.js:133
```

as well as a bunch of other errors - their code is *terrible* and they don't seem to care as long as it loads.

If I run my python code without `use_firefox=True`, I get

```
File "/Users/ptomblin/src/foo/bar/scrape_fltplan.py", line 78, in login
    driver.get("https://www.foo.bar.com/")
  File "/Users/ptomblin/.local/share/virtualenvs/alink-u2yY1HCk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/ptomblin/.local/share/virtualenvs/alink-u2yY1HCk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/ptomblin/.local/share/virtualenvs/alink-u2yY1HCk/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (https://www.foo.bar.com/js/menu.js#9)
Stacktrace:
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError (ScriptRuntime.java:4130)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError (ScriptRuntime.java:4108)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError (ScriptRuntime.java:4141)
```

and a similar stack trace on the Selenium remote server side. If I uncomment out the `driver.error_handler = SeleniumHandler()`, it means I don't see that exception on the python side, but since it gets the exception it doesn't continue processing the other JavaScript on that page and so it doesn't finish loading the stuff I need in the DOM.

Is there any way to make the Remote server ignore the JavaScript error and keep going?

Comment: Well, what do you know - the horrible JavaScript error they introduced was caused by them making the site so it works without JavaScript. I turned off JS and now I can crawl it.

Comment: I'd like to enter a new programming term: **Regressive Enhancement** (Noun): An attempt at progressive enhancement which causes a catastrophic error that, by coincidence, results in the very enhancement being attempted.